# Logic Apps: Filter special characters from array

Tags: azure-logic-apps

lets say you have an array called ips:

```
[
  "[\"185.241.208.232",
  "194.26.192.64",
  "171.25.193.25",
  "\"]"
]
```

[image]

how would I filter out the [" and "] out of the array.

the array that enters the watchlist should look like:

```
[
  "185.241.208.232",
  "194.26.192.64",
  "171.25.193.25"
]
```

i need to do this without using a for loop to look at every item for the \ (as the actual list is very long and it'll make the logic app run for some time). i happen to know the \ exists at the start and end of the list.

Comment: Can you provide your ask clearly with flow images

Comment: how would I filter out the [" and "] out of the array.

what do mean by this @HarriS?

Comment: i've added a screenshot to show my use-case. where i want to create a watchlist but the \ in the array is preventing me. i've also included an example of my ideal output. (in my actual use case i've receiving this array from a http request.

Comment: ok, got, provided an answer below.

Comment: is there a way to do this with out a for loop. if that ip list happens to have 10K ips it will be very slow.

Comment: AFAIK, No using loop only this is possible

Comment: do you know how to slice an array with expressions. like in python mylist=[1,2,3] , mylist[1:] would output [2,3]. the equivalent of this but with expressions? i figured it would use something like len(), then one of the index functions. to achieve [1:-1]

Comment: No @HarriS but , ill check too about that

Comment: @HarriS I added a solution not requiring a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use [`For each`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops?tabs=consumption#for-each) loops to achieve the desired result - this is very inefficient.

You need to use only 2 actions:

1. [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#select-action) - to remove unnecessary characters from each item of your array:

[image]

Code View:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": [
            "[\"185.241.208.232",
            "194.26.192.64",
            "171.25.193.25",
            "\"]"
        ],
        "select": "@replace(replace(replace(item(), '[', ''), ']', ''), '\"', '')"
    }
}
```

2. [`Filter array`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations?tabs=consumption#filter-array-action) - to remove empty items from the array:

[image]

Code View:

```
{
    "inputs": {
        "from": "@body('Select')",
        "where": "@greater(length(item()), 0)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below **`design`** to get expected results:

[image]

Then:

```
replace(replace(items('for_each'),'["',''),'"]','')
```

[image]

Then:

```
empty(item())
```

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

**`CodeView:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Filter_array": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@variables('var2')",
                    "where": "@equals(empty(item()), false)"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "For_each": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Query"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Append_to_array_variable": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "value": "@outputs('Compose')"
                        },
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Compose": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "AppendToArrayVariable"
                    },
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@replace(replace(items('for_each'),'[\"',''),'\"]','')",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@variables('var')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "[\"185.241.208.232",
                                "194.26.192.64",
                                "171.25.193.25",
                                "\"]"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Initialize_variable_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "var2",
                            "type": "array"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```